# How to tap on UI element which does not have Text or content Description using Android UI Automator Viewer?

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I am currently working with Android UI Automator viewer . I want to click on the button which does not have it's text or content description, how do I click on the button ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please add your work yet and make it easier for us to help

Answer (score 0):

Before being able to click on the button you need to make sure your test is setup correctly. I recommend checking out [this sample by Google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/ui/uiautomator/BasicSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/uiautomator/BasicSample/ChangeTextBehaviorTest.java) if you haven't already done this, you can copy pretty much all of it apart from the two tests. Make sure you change the package name from their `com.example.android.testing.uiautomator.BasicSample` to your package name.

As long as you have an id for your button in your layout you should be able to click on it.

```
UiObject2 button = mDevice.findObject(By.res(BASIC_SAMPLE_PACKAGE, "your_button_id"));
button.click();
```